# Is the Access 2010 ACCDB the same in Access 2016/Office 365?

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-office, office365

We have a CRM that is built on Access VBA. I upgraded it from a Access 2003 MDB file to a 2010 ACCDB.

We are on the cusp of upgrading to Office 365 and I would like to do some testing/research on the move from 2010 to  365's 2016 version of access.

It seems that the ACCDB file is stable between version of 2010 to the 365/2016 version. Is that true? I cannot find documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for accdb files is constant between Access 2007 to Access 2016. However, later updates of Access 365/2016 offer support for the `BigInt` data type, which is not backwards compatible with older versions of Office (even older versions of Office 2016).

As long as you don't use the `BigInt` data type, and you don't use import functions that create new tables on data sources that might be imported as `BigInt`, you should be able to open the same file in Access 2010 and Access 2016.

If you use an older version of Access 2016, without `BigInt` support, you should be able to use them without a real chance of breaking compatibility.

Comment: So the only database and programmatic change between 2010 and 2016 is BigInt Support?

Comment: @Elias Yup. There are multiple features scrapped, UI changes, VBA 7 vs 7.1, but these all shouldn't affect file compatibility. The only feature change affecting compatibility is BigInt support. There have been some questions about VBA code breaking, but they're likely related to other factors changing, such as the presence of references (I currently support a production database where ~70% of clients use Office 2010, rest Office 2016).

Comment: May be that was true in 2018 but in 2022 I have some accdb file samples which are not related to bigint but can't be opened in Access 2007 after working with them in 365